# div content on scrolled bottom html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to ask about div content scroll listener (not page).
so I have an html code where the appearance of the web design resembles a native application. what I want to do is how do I detect if the user has scrolled down the content div? not a page because my web page for him is only silent, but the one that moves in the div. my div code is something like this

```
<div class="product-list-item">
   //product card
   //product card
</div>
```

[image]

and when i scroll like this

[image]

I want to see other products using ajax when it reaches the bottom of the div, for now I
still using the manual button to load other products.

I've used this code but it's not working.

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
      }
  });
</script>
```

does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this:

```
<div class="product-list-item" id="target">
   //product card
   //product card
</div>
```

You can use this script to check if you reached your target div:

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height() >= $('#target').position().top) {
                console.log('Target Reached');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

You can use this approach to only execute the code once , once it has reached the target div

```
<script>
        let isReached = false;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height() >= $('#ftr').position().top && isReached == false) {
                isReached = true;
                //ajax call
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, i have try this code, the scroll function still not works:" and i have to try debug alert outside if statement, but the `code`$(window).scroll `code` is not work @YESSINE

Comment: @AdityaRizqi
Could you check console for any errors? (F12 in chrome then go console)
Double check to see if jQuery is imported in the document you're executing this since this won't work without it
you should have something like this at the bottom for the html/php document
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js""></script>`

Comment: owh i see, i will try it, thank you :" @YESSINE